# Emulator is showing error {firebase.App() not found} while using firebase authentication with React Native using expo-cli

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-tools, expo

While using functionality of authentication through firebase, emulator is showing error i.e.{ you attempted to use a firebase module that is not installed on your android project by calling firebase.app() }.Please help me to resolve this error.
I'm using Expo as command line input.

```
react-native version -0.63.6,
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.2.3"
```

[image: emulator]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expo client, you should not use react-native-firebase modules because they are not compatible with expo client.

However, you can use firebase javascript SDK instead. It is all explained [there](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/).

Answer (score 1):

**Update 02-12-2021**

Guys expo's **eas-build** is now public. You can add custom native codes and use react-native-firebase. Here is the link to a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=658s) tutorial. The video is short and super easy to follow. Here is the  [link to the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/)

**Previous answer**

Currently, **Firebase** does not work in react native if you are using the mobile configuration. However, if you use the web configuration it will work. Here is the [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hPgQWbWmEk&t=3309s). Watch from `38:20` to set up.